# Directory string interpolation for file creation

Tags: c#, .net

### I have created something that has flash drive insertion and removal events to generate a key to use for a USB drive authenticator.

Everything works perfectly upto when I try to create the key, I can't seem to interpolate the drive label.

```
string BID = Sys.GetBaseboardID();
string CID = Sys.GetMachineGuID();
string k = "32 char string"; // this is where my 256 bit key goes
string iv = "16 char string"; // this is where my 128 bit key goes
string bencr = AES.Encrypt(BID, k, iv); //sorry for my strange variable names
string cencr = AES.Encrypt(CID, k, iv);
string keydir = "{dName}:\b4nk.key"; // <-- Here is the problem

StreamWriter w_r;
w_r = File.CreateText(@keydir);
w_r.WriteLine("WARNING: TOUCHING THIS FILE WILL REMOVE YOUR AUTHENTICATION\n");
w_r.WriteLine(bencr);
w_r.WriteLine(cencr);
w_r.Close();
File.SetAttributes(@keydir, FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

As you can most likely imagine, the output of the `keydir` string is the following: `{dName}:4nk.key`

**There are a couple problems:**

1. \b seems to act similarly to \n (I assume it is used for 'break' or something)
2. I need it to be a directory, so it requires the `@` character at the start.
3. If I try to do something like: `string keydir = dName + ":\b4nk.key"` although it works, the \b problem remains.

### Solution

thanks to @Joshua Robinson I have learned something really interesting, my recent usage of python had me confused here.

to fix this you can combine the `$` and `@` characters to get an interpolated, verbatim string literal:

`string keydir = $@"{dName}:\b4nk.key";`

Comment: try $"{dName}:\\b4nk.key";

Comment: an interpolated string has à leading `$` infront: `$"MyString"`.

Comment: Voting to close as "typo". Interpolated strings must be prefixed with a `'$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolation expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a result string, items with interpolation expressions are replaced by the string representations of the expression results. This feature is available starting with C# 6.

So, in order to get an interpolated string, your string literal needs to begin with the `$` character.

`string keydir = $"{dName}:\b4nk.key";`

You should also check out the documentation on [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). Specifically, the second item in the list which describes verbatim string literals.

> To indicate that a string literal is to be interpreted verbatim. The @ character in this instance defines a verbatim string literal. Simple escape sequences (such as "\" for a backslash), hexadecimal escape sequences (such as "\x0041" for an uppercase A), and Unicode escape sequences (such as "\u0041" for an uppercase A) are interpreted literally. Only a quote escape sequence ("") is not interpreted literally; it produces one double quotation mark. Additionally, in case of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences ({{ and }}) are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters. The following example defines two identical file paths, one by using a regular string literal and the other by using a verbatim string literal. This is one of the more common uses of verbatim string literals.

It appears you've added the special `@` character to the name of your variable, `keydir`. Using the `@` character at the beginning of a variable name would allow you to use a keyword as a variable name, for example if you wanted a variable named `class` you could name it `@class`. Placing `@` at the start of the variable name will not cause it to be interpreted literally if it is a `string`, you have to place it at the front of the `string` literal.

You can combine the `$` and `@` characters to get an interpolated, verbatim string literal:

`string keydir = $@"{dName}:\b4nk.key";`

Answer (score 2):

You´re mixing two things here: string-interpolation and a verbatim string.

The first one is indicated using the `$` infront:

```
var myString = $"{ data }whateverComesNext";
```

The verbatim simply escapes any slahes. As you already assumed `\b` is an escape-sequence. You have to escape that sequence, e.g. by using `\\b`. Alternativly use both verbatim **and** interpolation:

```
var myString = $@"{ data }\banyothertext"`.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to have in file `{dName}:\b4nk.key` not `{dName}:4nk.key`
you can replace all '\' chars to '\\'. \ breaks another \ and it remains \ but without it's function or simply add @ before string

`string a = "asdak\\nsa\\b"`

Or `string a = @"asdak\nsa\b";`

I hope it helps

Comment: that´s not string-interpolation.

Comment: `dName` appears to be a drive letter, so the following `:\ ` string is just part of the drive portion of the path, followed by the file name, `"b4nk.key"`. The question is regarding string interpolation, and why the variable `{dName}` is not resolving to it's value inside the string.